# How to get the Google Analytics global function name?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Hi all super google analytics rockstars,

How can I get the google analytics global function name, when it's renamed from the install script.

E.g.:

```
 (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','__gaTracker');
```

I want to get the "__gaTracker" function name that was renamed (or something else).

Just setting the context, we have a script that runs on client's websites and sends events to google analytics. Sometimes they have the "ga" function and we call `ga('send'...)` but if they rename it, we need to call (e.g.) `__gaTracker('send'...)`.

Is there any way to get the global function that was renamed.

Thanks in advance !!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be accessed via `window['GoogleAnalyticsObject'];`, it will give you the `GLOBAL` variable name. Hope this is what you were asking for.

just do a <kbd>**F12**</kbd> and paste your code in console here, you will see SO global function name,

```
console.log(window['GoogleAnalyticsObject'];) // ouputs ga
```

Comment: Thanks @anirban-n, but if I run `window['GoogleAnalyticsObject']` it just returns the default "ga", not the '__gaTracker'.

Comment: When I try it I get the renamed tracker. Are you by chance using the ga debugger ? Apparently (according to Simo Ahava who usually knows what he is talking about) the debugger code always displays "ga" even for renamed trackers (https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/I6bjoBsO3yQ)

Comment: You're right @anirban-n. I know what's happening. There's 2 GA scripts installed. There's the first installation with __gaTracker (where the tracker is actually created with UA-XXX), then there's another installation with 'ga'. So the GoogleAnalyticsObject gets overwritten and returns 'ga'.

Answer (score 4):

Google recommends to use both "GoogleAnalyticsObject" and "ga" variables for GA tracker lookup:

```
// © Google Inc.
// This function works even if the site  
// has customized the ga global identifier. 
var ga = window[window['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] || 'ga'];
```

[Full example on developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/plugins#creating)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to return "ga" string (in your case). If Yes, you have to ovewrite GoogleAnalyticsObject initiation with new default loader. Mr. Arniban N is right.

Comment: You're both right. I know what's happening. There's 2 GA scripts installed in that website. There's the first installation with __gaTracker (where the tracker is actually created with UA-XXX), then there's another installation with 'ga'. So the GoogleAnalyticsObject gets overwritten and returns 'ga'.